# Force, displacement and work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work, displacement

Can it still be called work if the force exerted is in the same direction with the displacement of the body, however, the force is so little that it actually does not do anything on the body while stationary, and the change in displacement is actually caused by another pulling force in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use the resolved forces to calculate the work done (subtract opposing forces).